# Limit collapse_key count in android GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

StackOverflow, i need your help! I've read gcm documentation here http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html and don't understand fully what means "GCM only allows a maximum of 4 different collapse keys to be used by the GCM server per device at any given time". I want to explain for myself it. I can assume that if on my phone N applications are installed (facebook, twitter, instagramm, myMail, facebook and other), there is no guarantee that when my device for example will return to online, GCM will choose collapse_key of my app. Am i right or no?? If I am right in what sense of this collapse key if there is no guarantee that it will work and that my app will receive at the right time the necessary notification? I need to point that pattern "Sync-to-load" is very preferrable for me and i want to use it, but I am afraid that problems will begin when user will be write in comments "My device come back online, but i missed all messages:(("

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit on GCM collapse_keys is on a **per app** level and is not affected by what other apps the user has installed on their phone.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! Now I'm calm :)

Comment: I have a one question more about gcm and reported it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653569/gcm-statistic-errors). Maybe do you know answer for my question, I will be very grateful to you.